# How to recover gitlabwiki from files on filesystem

Tags: gitlab, markdown, wiki, recovery

We had a corruption of the VHDX backup file. We were able to recover files from the file system. So we have some corrupted markdown. How to find specific wiki files for a specific project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, git repositories are stored in the directory `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data`, but this might have been changed to a different location on your server. Check with whoever configured Gitlab to see if the `git_data_dirs` variable has been set, and what it's set to. Once you have the right location, you can `cd /path/to/git-data/repositories/@hashed`.

In the `git-data` directory there is always a `repositories` dir. This directory has a dir for each of your Gitlab groups, and a few other things. From my experience, *ignore them all*, they're just distractions. The actual repository data is somewhere in the `@hashed` directory, but you'll find it's difficult to explore.

When stored to disk, Gitlab hashes the project ID and stores it in two levels of the first 4 characters from the hash like:

```
@hashed
  -> d9
    -> 3f
      -> d93fe50149658661312a9e0b35558d84f6c6d3da797f552a9657fe0558ca40cdef.git
```

If it ends in `.git` that's the project itself. If it has `.wiki.git` that's the wiki repo you're looking for here.

Fortunately, we don't have to guess at the exact string to be hashed or the hashing algorithm because Gitlab gives us the hashed value (and the path within the `@hashed` directory) on the Project's Admin page (`gitlab.example.com/admin/projects/example-group/my-project`). It will look like:
`Gitaly relative path: @hashed/29/3f/d93fe50149658661312a9e0b35558d84f6c6d3da797f552a9657fe0558ca40cdef.wiki.git`

Once you have the files, you could tar them together, then scp to another system, or whatever else you need to do. For example:

```sh
tar -cvzf project_files.tar.gz /path/to/git-data/repositories/@hashed/29/3f/d93fe50149658661312a9e0b35558d84f6c6d3da797f552a9657fe0558ca40cdef.wiki.git

mv project_files.tar.gz /home/me

# then from another system
scp gitlab.example.com:/home/me/project_files.tar.gz .
```

The configuration options to change the git data location: https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/configuration.html#storing-git-data-in-an-alternative-directory

Information about the hashed names: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/repository_storage_types.html#hashed-storage